# Firebase child() vs. Angularfire $firebaseObject

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to understand WHEN Firebase actually loads the data to the client vs. doing "lazy load" (only download the data when it's needed). The reason is that I am saving images (base64) in Firebase (please don't ask why as it's only few hundred MBs). So there are two choices:

```
  // With typical Firebase
  var imagesRef = Ref.child('images');

  // With Angularfire
  var imagesObj = $firebaseObject(Ref.child('images'));
```

`Ref` is just a reference to my Firebase URL.

I know with Angularfire, there is `$loaded()` which makes me think Angularfire actually loads all the data AT ONCE and makes it available when you call `$firebaseObject()` right away. **Is it correct?**

As for using `child()`, I don't see any `load()` event to catch based on the documentation. Maybe I missed it. **But does it load all data from the server to client?**

If I have like 500MB of images, I definitely don't want this load-all-at-once happening.

Comment: Ref.child() just creates the reference to child location. does not load anything. I suspect that the same is with the angular wrapper.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$firebaseObject()` will immediately load the data (see https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/FirebaseObject.js#L420). But you can easily check this by opening the Network tab of your Chrome console and checking the web socket traffic.

Comment: Judging by the fact that the path is called `images`, it's probably a collection. Thus, you should use `$firebaseArray()` instead of `$firebaseObject()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firebase retrieve the data when you call .on on a ref

As not widely know, all the data are retrieved in one piece (wether you call .on 'value' or .on 'child_added'), so you better paginate your result using orderByFirst / Last, or using [firebase util](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util)

What angular fire does when you instanciate a firebaseObject / array is calling on 'value' / 'child_added' from within the constructor function of the instance, so yes , the data are retrieved almost instantly (but in a defer hence the $loaded() function).

Check out the source code of the [Object manager](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/FirebaseObject.js) and the constructor of $firebaseObject for instance, it's pretty clear

Comment: It seems like Angularfire is lacking lots of features (missing orderByFirst ) and ended doing things causing performance issues.

Comment: angularfire just sync your data with firebase based on the ref you give , it's up to you to use orderBy something or condition on the ref before to build an angularfire instance from it. You may want to check out some firebase util live exemples on their website

Comment: @HP: AngularFire is not the Firebase SDK with `$` in front of the method names. It's a binding library to help sync local Angular view data to Firebase. A read of the guide will go a great deal to helping you use this tool appropriately and save energy and time inventing wheels. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html

Comment: So in a sense, one should use Firebase SDK as normal and only touches Angularfire when you need 3-way binding at that exact location. Because my misconception was that Angularfire has everything needed. But look like it's not a full 100% port over.

Comment: i'm currently trying to build a model layer on top of angularfire, you may wana take a look a it https://github.com/itkin/angularfire-resource ...